# Método para buscar un elemento en un menú de opciones en forma de árbol

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente clase (las anotaciones de @Getter y @Setter son de una librería que te genera automáticamente los métodos de get y set):

```
public class MenuItem {

  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String name;
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String src;
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private List<MenuItem> children;
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private MenuItem parent;
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private int level;

  public MenuItem(String name, int level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    children = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
  }

  public void addChild(MenuItem node) {
    children.add(node);
  }

  public void appendChild(MenuItem child) {
    if (children == null)
      children = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
    children.add(child);
  }
}
```

La cual va a contener las distintas opciones de un menú para una aplicación.

```
List<MenuItem> menus = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

MenuItem m1 = new MenuItem("Solicitudes", 1);
MenuItem m1_lv1 = new MenuItem("Listado", 2);
m1_lv1.setSrc("/listado");
m1_lv1.setParent(m1);
m1.addChild(m1_lv1);
m1_lv1 = new MenuItem("Nueva Solicitud", 2);
m1_lv1.setSrc("/nuevaSolicitud");
m1_lv1.setParent(m1);
m1.addChild(m1_lv1);

menus.add(m1);
```

En este breve ejemplo el menú ha quedado de esta forma:

Solicitudes:

1. Listado (src = "/listado")
2. Nueva Solicitud (src = "/nuevaSolicitud")

Como veis voy a tener una lista, que cada elemento puede tener n hijos y así sucesivamente, formando un árbol de opciones.
El problema que tengo, es que no se como hacer una función que dado el campo "src" (va a ser único) me devuelva el MenuItem que corresponda con ese campo.

```
private MenuItem buscarMenuItem(String src) {
    
    
  }
```

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo puedes hacer de forma recursiva, entrando por el item principal, si su lista de items contiene el que tu quieres, lo devuelves, sino, por cada item de la lista buscas recursivamente otra vez, hasta que lo encuentres. Pero si los tienes identificados por  un nombre único, a lo mejor lo que te interesa, es que cuando crees un item, lo añadas a un mapa `Map<String, MenuItem>` de tal manera que encuentres el elemento que quieras en O(1) en lugar de buscarlo recursivamente que tiene mayor complejidad, posibilidad de llenar la pila, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes seguir los siguientes pasos:

```
BuscarMenuItem {
    Si el item actual es el que se busca
        Devuelve el actual

    Si el item actual no tiene hijos
        Devuelve null

    Recorre los hijos del item actual uno por uno
        Busca el item en el hijo
        Si el hijo encontró el item lo devuelve, sino pasa al siguiente hijo

    Si no encontró nada devuelve null
}
```

En código Java sería algo así:

```
public MenuItem buscarMenuItem(String src) {
    if (src.equals(this.src))
        return this;

    if (this.children.isEmpty())
        return null;

    for (MenuItem i : this.children) {
        MenuItem item = i.buscarMenuItem(src);
        if (item != null)
            return item;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Pones ese método dentro de tu clase `MenuItem`.

Luego para buscar lo puedes hacer así:

```
List<MenuItem> menus = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();

MenuItem m1 = new MenuItem("Solicitudes", 1);
MenuItem m1_lv1 = new MenuItem("Listado", 2);
m1_lv1.setSrc("/listado");
m1_lv1.setParent(m1);
m1.addChild(m1_lv1);
m1_lv1 = new MenuItem("Nueva Solicitud", 2);
m1_lv1.setSrc("/nuevaSolicitud");
m1_lv1.setParent(m1);
m1.addChild(m1_lv1);

menus.add(m1);

MenuItem item = null;
for (MenuItem i : menus) {
    item = i.buscarMenuItem("/listado");
    if (item != null)
        break;
}

if (item != null) {
    //item contiene el ítem encontrado
} else {
    System.out.println("No encontrado");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.
Con tus indicaciones he podido modificar la prueba que tenia entre manos para que funcione.